# Rendering image with lens distort node and transparent background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, export, compositing-nodes, transparency

I try rendering my image as a png with an rgba channel but when I put on the lend distortion node in the compositer it makes it have a black background.

Comment: Please show an image of your nodes and the result you are getting. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that's because this node is not a simple deformation node, it also affects color (if Dispersion is used). But you can use something like that :
[image]

Comment: Upvoted: but, note if you were animating the lens distort from the image port, duplicating the lens distort for the alpha does not include animation keys. I needed to re-create those keys on the alpha port's lens distort node to get my effect to works as expected with trans. background.